# What is the equivalent of 'miffed'?

Tags: words, word-requests

In the sense of 'mildly offended/annoyed'. Is there a single word expressing this, or would it just be 少し + adjective?

Example sentence:

> I'm miffed that he suddenly hung up yesterday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would hear us say:

・むかついた

・むっとした

・むっときた

・しゃくにさわった

You could, if you wanted, insert 「ちょっと or 少{すこ}し」 in front of any of those expressions.

The first three sound colloquial and slightly slangy and the last one, not at all.

「むっ/ムッ」 is an onomatopoeic word describing a light kind of anger or annoyance.